# Preview de documentos que tengo en el servidor con angular

Tags: html, angular

```html
<ng-template #content let-modal>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{selectedFile.name}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <!-- {{safeURL(selectedFile.source) }} -->
            <!-- {{safeURL(selectedFile.source).changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity }} -->
            <!-- <iframe src="localhost:3000/{{selectedFile.source}}" widthwidthframeborder="0"></iframe> -->
            <!-- <iframe src='{{safeURL(selectedFile.source)}}' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
            <!-- <iframe *ngIf="isYoutube(selectedFile.source)" [src]='safeURL(selectedFile.source)' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
            <!-- [viewerUrl]="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=%URL%&embedded=true" -->
            <!-- <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://dmsp.ccafs.cgiar.org/data/1_Policy_Documents/2015-06_CCAFS_Data_Management_Strategy.pdf"></iframe> -->
            <!-- <iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=https://dmsp.ccafs.cgiar.org/data/1_Policy_Documents/2015-06_CCAFS_Data_Management_Strategy.pdf'
                width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank'
                    href='http://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank'
                    href='http://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe> -->
            <!-- <ngx-doc-viewer 
                [url]="safeURL(selectedFile.source)" viewer="url" style="width:100%;height:50vh;">
            </ngx-doc-viewer> -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning" (click)="modal.close(selectedFile.source)">Source</button> -->
        <a *ngIf="selectedFile.type === '1'" href="{{selectedFile.source}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" target="_blank">Go to Resource</a>
        <a *ngIf="selectedFile.type === '0'" href="http://localhost:3000/{{selectedFile.source}}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" download="{{selectedFile.source}}" >Download Resource</a>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

no se si es posible mostrar una previsualización del documento seleccionado en un modal HTML (.docx .pptx .pdf), tengo servidos los documentos con la libreria serve, si tienen alguna idea de como hacerlo o que librerias podria usar, muchas gracias

Comment: que tecnologías estas usando? codigo?

Comment: Acabo de añadir el codigo que estoy usando para mostrar el preview, intentando usar iframe, pero cuando voy a ver si se está mostrando me aparece en blanco

Comment: porque todo dentro del `<form>` está comentado?

Comment: son pruebas que he realizado pero no me han funcionado